# How To Get Server and Client to Server Travel Based on Logic in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: logic, game-development, unreal-engine5

I'm working on a multiplayer game in Unreal Engine and there is a lobby where players can start and join up. When players are ready I have a platform actor that is a trigger and detects how many players are standing on it and it increases an int variable that is on the gamemode (I know this is probably incorrect to do but I have tried loads of different things). In the tick function of the game mode i have logic stating basically if there is more than two players, from that int variable it will fire the server travel but when it fires it causes the client to crash and the host wont travel. How can I implement this logic and fire the server travel successfully does anyone know ? Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that by using the [Get Overlapping Actors](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Collision/GetOverlappingActors/) function inside your Platform's Blueprint. It gets all the actors, which you can filter by Class so you can choose Pawns or Player Pawns, then get the number of elements from the array it returns.

Also, are you aware of [RPCs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Networking/Actors/RPCs/) and Multicasting? If not, I suggest giving them a read since they are a necessity for Multiplayer games, especially if it is for using UE's own Multiplayer support.

Create a Server/Multicast RPC depending on whether it is a Server or not inside your Character Blueprint, then call it from your Player Pawn 0 (which is the client's character in that specific instance of the game) in the Platform Blueprint (which you cast to whatever class you're using for your character), and you'll hopefully have a working version of your code.

If you don't know about RPCs and Replication and are reading this, and not understanding anything, I swear it'll make sense after you read about them. It's a complicated concept, especially with all the server shenanigans but a necessity.

If you don't want to clutter your Character Blueprint, you can also use [Interfaces](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Interfaces) but that's somewhat difficult to explain without getting into the details.

Comment: Hi there ! Thanks for getting back to me Khosbilegt ! I have actually solved this problem and I do know about RPC'S and Interfaces but now I'm stuck with another problem where I have a boolean in the characters player controller which will be set to true or false and when server travel commences I want the characters to keep that same controller they had with the variable but I can't figure out how since the controller gets reset to default on Server travel.

Comment: Player Controllers should persist throughout the game, so it should still have that boolean. Maybe it's because you're sending a Server RPC and then a Multicast, meaning it changes on the server with the Server RPC and then resets with the Multicast RPC? 

Should probably add a branch there to check whether it's a server, and not change it for the multicast.

Comment: They should persist okay, I was looking online and saw one place saying that values do reset online in the player controller on server travel. I’ll have to see where it’s getting reset and try rectify that so ! Thanks again !

Comment: That's on me. Player Controllers do reset on Server Travel, but what you can do to work around the problem is use [GameInstance](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UGameInstance/) instead, which actually persists.

Comment: Yeah I have used game instance for other things as I knew it would persist but trying to figure out then linking the controller variable to the same character I was thinking of comparing between the uniqueID from player state and if the two unique IDs between game instance (that is saved) and then on post login after server travel from the new controller got, if they match then set the variable on the controller, I suppose. I’d like to hear if you think that might work. That’s the only thing I can think of at this point to be honest. Thanks so much once again for all the help and getting back!

Comment: Also it’s no worries that you thought they didn’t reset ! : )

Comment: One way to "cheat" the annoying part would be to write all the necessary info into a text or json file, then read that later when necessary instead of passing them around. I don't know whether it's possible to write to a file and read it in Blueprints since I've only done that with C++ with [FFileHelper](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/FFileHelper/), but reading and parsing json is simple with the [VaRest](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/varest-plugin) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ken ! Yeah I am working in c++, personally prefer to try and write out in c++ first before resulting to blueprint but that is definitely a good idea instead of passing though different scripts so thanks for that ! Still trying to find a way to have a constant reference to a certain player so I can change only their pawn and not the others after server travel. Quite difficult to find something to work.